# onActivityResult not called inside fragment

Tags: android

I know this question has been answered many a times in stack overflow but none of the solutions worked for me. I need to choose a pdf file from the device. The startActivityResult() gets called, I am able to choose a pdf file but then the onActivityResult is never called. The strange thing is it was working before perfectly but suddenly it is no more responding.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
```

**Fragment.java**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null )

//do something

        }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ConnectivityManager CM = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ninfo = CM.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.upload_prax && ninfo!=null && ninfo.isConnected() ) {

            if (permissionexternal == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/pdf");
            fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
```

Comment: Show any error or hint ??

Comment: How you are starting your Activity (which returns result)?

Comment: Nothing. I even debugged the app but nothing came up! @MohammadAli

Comment: sorry didn't get you! @GokulNathKP

Comment: can you try to Rebuild the project or clean the project ?@digital_pro

Comment: post code related to your startActivityforResult() call

Comment: @JyotiJK I have updated the code.

Comment: @pskink yes I did but nothing shows up

Comment: `fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);` instead of this, you can just write `startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);`

Comment: Nothing changed! @MohammadAli

Comment: you should debug your code and check where your code is break. and `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK` replace with `resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK`

Comment: Still the same. Debugging do not show anything  @EktaBhawsar

Answer (score 3):

In your fragment, use

```
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And you don't need to add `onActivityResult()` for your activity . Just remove

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

and in your fragment,

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null )
             //do something
           }

         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On Activity Result Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          // add toast to check whether it is working or not

 }
```

Comment: It is still the same. The toast doesn't show up.

Comment: In my case, It worked. Can you please rebuild your project then execute it

Comment: Not working. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Request which you made in fragment. Response of that request you can retrieve in activity which you set the fragment.

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
             if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null )

    //do something

            }
```

this code should be in parent activity of fragment.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: then there should be other error so pls try debugging the code line by line

Answer (score 0):

Try this in activity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                switch (fragment.getTag()) {
                    case "Set your fragment name":
                        int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE  = 138;
                        fragment.onActivityResult(PICK_IMAGE_SINGLE_MULTI, resultCode, data);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't  work!

Comment: What was the error you get ?

Comment: No error. It works like before.